# Auth::attempt($credentials) Always returns false in Laravel 8.76.2

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I'm using Auth::attempt($credentials) in Laravel 8.7, it always returns false.

My Login Blade Is

resources/views/login/login.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('login.custom') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        @error('email')
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        @error('password')
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="icheck-primary">
              <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
              <label for="remember">
                Remember Me
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign In</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
      </form>
```

Router

```
Route::post('custom-login', [LoginController::class, 'customLogin'])->name('login.custom');
```

My Controller code is like this - I'm accessing the controller using a router

LoginController.php

```
public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        //dd(print_r($request));
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        // $email = $request->input('email');
        // $password = $request->input('password');
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            return "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Fail";
        }

        //return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }
```

When I'm using Auth::attempt($credentials), returning always a false statement. Please help me to find out the actual problem or suggest me best solution.
I have tried many combinations to solve this problem but still not working.

[This is my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/236mh.jpg)

[This is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZ2a.jpg)

Comment: is the password hashed in the database?

Comment: No, the password is not hashed in the database, I have added a screenshot "This Is My Table structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/236mh.jpg "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hash the password in the database. The authentication system is expecting the password to be hashed in the database. It will do a hash check against the plain text version (user submitted value) and the hashed password from the database.

> "If the user is found, the **hashed** password stored in the database will be compared with the `password` value passed to the method via the array."

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Authentication - Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: Yes, When I have Hashed the password in the database it's working fine, Thanks alot

Comment: I have every file same as yours and also put hashed password in db, but for me it is still returning Fail...

Comment: This works, it was my bad.